# Authorization with AppdataPreferences

Tags: google-drive-api

I was not able to implement the authorization with [AppdataPreferences](https://github.com/googledrive/appdatapreferences-android). I'm following the documentation on Github but it doesn't ask user for permission after I set it up.

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential =
    GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata");
credential.setSelectedAccountName(emailAddress);
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the correct exception and display the auth dialog to the user, like:

```
syncer.setOnUserRecoverableAuthExceptionListener(
    new OnUserRecoverableAuthExceptionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onUserRecoverableAuthException(
        final UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
    // show user a notification to ask for permissions again.
    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), 123);
  }
});
```